# LWC Callout - which is the best option?

Tags: lightning-web-components, callout

I am making a LWC component. It should make a GET callout to an endpoint and receive JSON data.

I have 2 options:

1. Make the callout in Javascript controller
2. Make the callout in Apex controller

My questions are:

1. Which one is better in a large enterprise org?
2. Can I run into some problems if my callouts are synchronous in the component?
3. Can I also use Queueable interface in an Apex class which I would call from my LWC component?

Comment: voting to close, as there are too many considerations when deciding which one to chose  and details are lacking. (also, multiple questions per post are discouraged.)

Comment: @glls Sorry about the multiple questions.

Comment: If you add in more specifics about your scenario (what information is it getting, how will it use that information, how often does it need to call, how often does the data change, what's the UI experience related to that data) - then it might be answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2 cents...

If the data is mainly needed client-side, get it from the client-side. The `fetch` API is asynchronous so there should be no blocking problems. The domains that can be accessed are limited to ones that are nominated as "CSP Trusted Sites" in the Setup UI so what is accessed can be locked down.

If the data is mainly needed server-side, get it there. Also get it server-side if secrets (including access tokens) or data that you don't want tampered with are involved. The domains that can be accessed are limited to ones that are nominated as "Remote Sites".

Comment: Hi, let's say that the data is shown in Salesforce. Based on what you said, does that mean that Salesforce (client sending callouts to endpoint) needs the data client-side? If server is the endpoint, then I need to take the data from the endpoint and display them in Salesforce. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Hi @DevelBase2, There is your user's "client" computer, the "Salesforce" server computer and the "other" server computer that you want to grab the data from. The data from both the "Salesforce" server and the "other" server end up viewed in your user's "client" computer. For e.g. a public city map you might go "client" <-> "other"; for e.g. a bank account interaction you would go "Salesforce" <-> "other" as secrets and critical data are involved.

Answer (score 2):

On top of @Keith C's answer, I would say if that end point is secured it is better to use server-side integration so the client never needs the details for accessing that end point - it is cleanly handled on the server and protects that end point from hacking by a user who inspects your delivered JavaScript to figure out what's going on. (This is basically the last part of Keith's answer, I just wanted to emphasise it.)

Comment: Hi, thanks. Does server-side integration mean sending callouts from Salesforce to the endpoint? I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. The "org" is the "server", the browser is the "client".